# I have two different domains with the same code, but one of them doesn't work. Why?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, host

I am using the same code with two sub-domains which are hosted on the same server. The code is working on the first one but not on the second one.

Could the reason be `$(document).ready( function()` because outside of `$(document).ready( function()` scripts are working?

The code is:

```
$("#xdiv").autocomplete("script/get_list.php", {
            width: 200,
            matchContains: true,
            selectFirst: false
        });

        $("#xdiv").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        $("#idmc").val(data[1]);
        $("#mcc").val(data[2]);

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean the scripts aren't working?  What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Are the scripts in the page, or in a referenced file?  Have you tried stepping through the code in FireBug or Chrome?

Comment: no error nothing it just doesnt work

Comment: I'm guessing that when you copied the code, somewhere in a file there you have a direct reference to the old sub domain... instead of the new one. maybe something like that...

Comment: even the folder name are same the only thing i changed their path and weird thing is some codes are working for example the below is working 
 
`$('.del_btn').click(function(){
  
       var del_id = $(this).attr('rel');
   if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this article? There is NO undo!"))
{
       $.post('script/delete.php', {delete_id:del_id}, function(data) {
        if(data == 'true') {
            $('#'+del_id).remove();alert('Article has been deleted!');
          }  
    else {alert('Article !');}
    });
}
return false;});
`

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with trying to run javascript from a different subdomain and can depend on the browser and security settings you have enabled. I'm just guessing as your question is unclear and doesn't contain steps to reproduce the problem.

If you have the old subdomain online still and need it to be until this one works, modify your host file (or something else if not on Windows) so that the old subdomain hits nothing. Now you should be able to get some meaningful errors showing you where your reference is.

Comment: what i did is i just moved all sources from one sub domain to another one forexample a.domain.com same script is working but b.domain.com its not working

Comment: This answer would have made a great comment!

Comment: thanks a lot guys,  i just solve it missing file what a stupid mistake